# Call Gesture Method Programmatically

Tags: ios

I am working on application where i need to call single tap gesture method without touch or swipe anything.I want to call that method when initWithframe method call.I just want to call this method programmatically only once.Please help me.How can i do this?thanking you.

Comment: Just call the method directly.. If it is not possible at this time you can call it with a delay performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:1 .

Comment: Just create a method that does what you want it to do and call it. If you aren't using anything specific to the actual recognizer just call its handler method passing in nil for the recognizer parameter.

Comment: @lukaswelte It's more common practice to to just do a `dispatch_async` on the main thread rather calling performSelector with a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and the method

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
}
```

To do it programatically.Why you need to manipulate tap.Just call the method directly.To call method use

```
[self handleTap:nil];
```

Comment: Read the question. He's asking how to call the method directly, rather than how to set up a recognizer with a handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self handleSwipe:gesture];
```