# Detect gesture recogniser and send action programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I’ve set/added Tap, Double Tap and Pinch gestures on UIImageView and upon user's interaction/touch, it’s working fine(sending all actions). But at specific event,

**I want to send these actions (tap, double tap & pinch) programatically on my image view without user’s touch/action.**

My query is to get gesture(s) implemented/added, in imageView. How can I get gesture added on ImageView?

Comment: This is possible but you need to pass nil as argument for gesture recognizer. Check this one for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189507/call-gesture-method-programmatically

Comment: @NiravD Yes, but that works upon user interaction. I need to get any one (according to requirement) of added gesture and perform action without user interaction.

Comment: That was I said check the line `[self handleTap:nil];` to call gesture method programmatically but for that you need to pass nil as argument there is no other option than this one

Comment: @NiravD OK, I see.. let me implement & check, what would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it's solution

```
for gesture in imageView.gestureRecognizers {
    imageViewAction(gesture: gesture)
}

func imageViewAction(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){

    if let _gesture = gesture as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
        if _gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 1 {
            print("Single Tap Gesture...")
        } else if _gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 2 {
            print("Double Tap Gesture...")
        } else  {
            print("Tap Gesture...")
        }
    } else if let _gesture = gesture as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
        print("Pinch Gesture...")
    }
}
```